# Возможно ли открыть браузер в песочнице при помощи пайтона?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, requests, request, bs4

- возможно ли открыть браузер в песочнице при помощи пайтона?
- есть какие-то библиотеки, которые можно открыть браузер в песочнице,  еще была совместима с request и bs4 (при парсинге)?
- как можно к своему коду  добавить строки решения капч, Xevil подключить для капчи?

Comment: у вас в тэгах ответ на "открыть браузер в песочнице при помощи пайтона" - [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html) же ж ;)

Comment: Можно реквестом тоже.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все ваши вопросы решает **Selenium + Selenoid** selenoid позволяет запускать сессии в докере, что предоставит вам изолированную среду. Для капчи скорее всего придется дописать модуль.

```
source = driver.page_source
# получить код страницы
```

После чего вы сможете парсить удобными вам модулями либо использовать сам selenium  для парсинга.

Comment: не проще ли создать venv, без selenoid?

Comment: возможно автору нужно непосредственно изолировать данные браузера, в данном случаи venv думаю не поможет.

Comment: Ок, посмотрю selenium!!!Да, именно изолировать браузер , открыть новую ссесию. Чтоб они непересекались даже данные не пересекались.

Comment: selenoid разворачивает сессии в докере, что дает изоляцию им

Comment: Ок, посмотрю .Спасибо!